# How to create page detail of each post wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi all I am a new of wordpress I try to create page detail of each post .but I can not ,I want when I clik link on post and go to page detail of post

This is my code get each post:

```
single.php:


 <?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                    // Previous/next post navigation.
                    twentyfourteen_post_nav();

                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                        comments_template();
                    }
                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

and this my event page:

```
<?php 

    $zerif_total_posts = get_option('posts_per_page'); /* number of latest posts to show */

    if( !empty($zerif_total_posts) && ($zerif_total_posts > 0) ):

        echo '<section class="latest-news" id="latestnews">';

            echo '<div class="container">';

                /* SECTION HEADER */

                echo '<div class="section-header">';

                    $zerif_latestnews_title = get_theme_mod('zerif_latestnews_title');

                    /* title */
                    if( !empty($zerif_latestnews_title) ):

                        echo '<h2 class="dark-text">' . $zerif_latestnews_title . '</h2>';

                    else:

                        echo '<h2 class="dark-text">' . __('Our Client','zerif-lite') . '</h2>';

                    endif;

                /* our Client */

                    if(is_active_sidebar( 'menu_client' )):
                    echo '<div id="menu_client">';

                    dynamic_sidebar( 'menu_client' );
                    echo '</div>';
                    endif;

                    /* subtitle */
                    $zerif_latestnews_subtitle = get_theme_mod('zerif_latestnews_subtitle');

                    if( !empty($zerif_latestnews_subtitle) ):

                        echo '<div class="dark-text section-legend">'.$zerif_latestnews_subtitle.'</div>';

                    endif;

                echo '</div><!-- END .section-header -->';

                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';

                echo '<div id="carousel-homepage-latestnews" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';

                    /* Wrapper for slides */

                    echo '<div class="carousel-inners" role="listbox">';


                        $zerif_latest_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => $zerif_total_posts, 'order' => 'DESC','ignore_sticky_posts' => true ) );

                        $newSlideActive = '<div class="item active">';
                        $newSlide       = '<div class="item">';
                        $newSlideClose  = '<div class="clear"></div></div>';
                        $i_latest_posts= 0;
                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        $page_id = get_the_ID(); 
                        if ( $zerif_latest_loop->have_posts() ) :

                            while ( $zerif_latest_loop->have_posts() ) : $zerif_latest_loop->the_post();

                                $i_latest_posts++;

                                if ( !wp_is_mobile() ){

                                        if($i_latest_posts == 1){
                                            echo $newSlideActive;
                                        }
                                        else if($i_latest_posts % 4 == 1){
                                            echo $newSlide;
                                        }

                                        echo '<div class="col-sm-3 latestnews-box">';

                                            echo '<div class="latestnews-img">';

                                                echo '<a class="latestnews-img-a" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">';

                                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                                                        the_post_thumbnail();
                                                    else:
                                                        echo '<img src="'.esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ).'/images/blank-latestposts.png" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                                                    endif; 

                                                echo '</a>';

                                            echo '</div>';

                                            echo '<div class="latesnews-content">';

                                                echo '<h3 class="latestnews-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';

                                                the_excerpt();

                                            echo '</div>';

                                        echo '</div><!-- .latestnews-box"> -->';

                                        /* after every four posts it must closing the '.item' */
                                        if($i_latest_posts % 4 == 0){
                                            echo $newSlideClose;
                                        }

                                } else {

                                    if( $i_latest_posts == 1 ) $active = 'active'; else $active = ''; 

                                    echo '<div class="item '.$active.'">';
                                        echo '<div class="col-md-3 latestnews-box">';
                                            echo '<div class="latestnews-img">';
                                                echo '<a class="latestnews-img-a" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
                                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                                                        the_post_thumbnail();
                                                    else:
                                                        echo '<img src="'.esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ).'/images/blank-latestposts.png" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                                                    endif; 
                                                echo '</a>';
                                            echo '</div>';
                                            echo '<div class="latesnews-content">';
                                                echo '<h3 class="latestnews-title"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
                                                the_excerpt();
                                            echo '</div>';
                                        echo '</div>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                }

                            endwhile;               
                        endif;  
                        $max_num_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
                    echo sofg_pagination($max_num_pages,$paged,$page_id);

                        if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
                            // if there are less than 10 posts
                            if($i_latest_posts % 4!=0){
                                echo $newSlideClose;
                            }
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata(); 

                    echo '</div><!-- .carousel-inner -->';

                    /* Controls */
                    echo '<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-homepage-latestnews" role="button" data-slide="prev">';

                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-homepage-latestnews" role="button" data-slide="next">';

                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</div><!-- #carousel-homepage-latestnews -->';

            echo '</div><!-- .container -->';
        echo '</section>';

endif;


?>
```

and I want when I click link on post it go to evenet_page_detail.php and see detail of content post who can help me pleast

Comment: http://westecmedia.com/events-2/

Comment: event page  this website I just continue from another web developer

Comment: now the link ok but when I click on each post. its lost description text

Comment: And dont have footer

Comment: u can see event page

Comment: http://westecmedia.com/christh-mash2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a specific way to create pages to access them properly.
Instead of naming your page as `evenet_page_detail.php` please make it as `single.php`

You can get more information about creating template from scratch here https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates

Comment: when I clik on eacht post I got nothing

Comment: Can you please share me the site link, so i can check

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). If you are using a custom post type for those posts you can create a new `single-{post-type}.php` file and when you enter in this detail post url, the file used will be this.

Also, you can create a custom template file for certain posts. Here is a [tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) for this. Basically you need to create a new file, for example `evenet_page_detail.php` and in the first line include:

```
<?php /* Template Name: My template name */ ?>
```

Then in the post admin you need to select this template name in the right column selector. When you select this template, this file will be used to show the detail of this post.

Comment: I am a new of wordpress, so do u have code for me bro ?

Comment: If you are using a custom post type named, for eample `event` you need to create a `singe-event.php` if you want you show a special template for the detail of those custom post type.

Comment: I don't know what do yo want to show in the detail page, take the content of the `single.php` file of your theme and adapt it.

Comment: Yes u can seee my code up ,and I want when I click link on post it go to page detail each post and show post detail ,bro